# Not able to send emails to extrenal email addresses with Spring Java mail

Tags: spring, smtp, jakarta-mail, mail-server

I have developed a spring Java Mail application in my project.I have configured my company mail server name in `Spring.xml` file. I am using `JavaMailSenderImpl`.

My spring.xml

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl"> 
 <property name="host" value="smtp.mycomp.com"/> 
</bean>
```

in my java class

```
public class ServiceEmail {

           public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {
            return mailSender;
        }

        @Autowired
        @Required
        public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
            this.mailSender = mailSender;

             message.setTo("example@gmail.com");
         message.setFrom(fromEmailAddress);

             try{
                this.mailSender.send(preparator);
               }catch(MailException e){

                   e.printstacktrac();

}
}

}
```

But when I use this I am not able to send any mails to gmail or any other mail cllients it's failing with `relaying denied exception`. But it's working well with my internal server.Is it my mail server Issue or Do i need to configure for each and every email client.How can configure this to work all the mail clients.Can I configure in XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#norelay) should help.